Django Form's HiddenInput does not save initial value
I have a simple form with two HiddenInputs. Submitted form does not save initial values for hidden fields. What am I missing?
forms.py
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(required=False, initial="Foo")
    bar = forms.CharField(required=False, initial="Bar", widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    is_true = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

views.py
def test_view(request):
    test_form = TestForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        test_form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if test_form.is_valid():
            print(test_form.cleaned_data)
    return render(request, "test.html", {"test_form": test_form})

output
{'foo': 'Foo', 'bar': '', 'is_true': False}

How can i get presettled values for hidden fields after form submit?
{'foo': 'Foo', 'bar': 'bar', 'is_true': True}


Are you not rendering the hidden input in your template?

@AbdulAzizBarkat, OMG, i really forgot a "hidden field" tag. It's a shame :( Thank You!
